# Javascript click button only once

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to hit the button after a form is filled in.
I have this currently:

```
document.getElementById("checkout_shipping_address_country").dispatchEvent(event);
document.getElementById("checkout_shipping_address_phone").value = userInfo.tel;
if ($("#checkout_shipping_address_province").length != 0) {
    document.getElementById("checkout_shipping_address_province").value = userInfo.state;
    $("input[name='commit']")[0].click();
}
```

It is an ajax form so it reloads after every click, in this case it seems like it's repeating the click, how can I only have it run once?

Comment: you need to remove click event handler from ajax code and put it outside

Comment: disable the button before sending AJAX request.. and re enable after you got the response

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button with jquery by adding,

```
$('#button_id').attr("disabled", true);
```

to enable the button again you can use

```
$('#button_id').removeAttr("disabled");
```